# Recarregar uma tabela AngularJS de tempos em tempos

Tags: angularjs

Minha página AngularJS exibe uma tabela com dados vindos de um JSON. O que eu quero é que a tabela seja atualizada de tempos em tempos, pois os dados são atualizados segundo a segundo e eu exibo apenas os últimos 10.

```
<tr ng-repeat="linha in linhas">
  <td ><abbr title="{{linha.descricao}}"> <a href=xxx.php?id_chamado={{linha.chamado}}>{{linha.chamado}}</a> </abbr>  </td>  
  <td >{{linha.data}}</td>
  <td >{{linha.nome}}</td>
  <td >{{linha.acao}}</td>
  <td >{{linha.cliente}}</td>   
  <td ><span class="label label-success">{{linha.sistema}}</span></td>
</tr>
```

Existe alguma maneira simples de de chegar neste objetivo ?

Meu controller, tudo funciona perfeito no load da pagina. eu só não sei invocar novamente esta função dentro do controller.

```
// JavaScript Document
var app = angular.module('sadApp', []);
app.controller('sadCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://192.168.0.14/a/historicochamadologlidosJson.php').
    success(function(data,  status, headers, config) {
        $scope.linhas = data;
    })
});
```

Já tentei este código aqui:

```
angular.element(document.getElementById('MainWrap')).scope().$apply();
```

onde MainWrap é o id da div:

```
<div ng-controller="sadCtrl" id="MainWrap">
```

Comment: Faça a consulta dos dados a cada X milissegundos, e no callback atualize `linhas` no seu model. Imagino que uma parte disso já esteja feita, não entendi em que parte exatamente você está tendo dificuldades.

Comment: A consulta está no controller, eu não sei como invoca-la novamente, pois o Angular já invoca automaticamente quando carrega-se a página.

Comment: Pode [incluir na perguntas os trechos relevantes do Controller](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/72533/edit), por favor?

Comment: OK - inclui o controller na pergunta. e o que eu já tentei fazer para invocar novamente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode tentar o código abaixo. O que eu fiz foi embrulhar numa função "privada" o trecho que busca os dados, e chamar essa função tanto na inicialização, quanto em intervalos determinados por um timer:

```
// JavaScript Document
var app = angular.module('sadApp', []);
app.controller('sadCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

    // Função que atualiza os dados
    // Somente disponível aqui dentro, não é método público
    function atualizaDados() {
        $http.get('http://192.168.0.14/a/historicochamadologlidosJson.php').
        success(function(data,  status, headers, config) {
            $scope.linhas = data;
        });
    }

    // Executa a função na inicalização
    atualizaDados();

    // Executa novamente a cada 60 segundos (60.000ms)
    // Altere o intervalo para o que achar mais adequado.
    setInterval(atualizaDados, 60000);
});
```

Comment: Funcionou Perfeito. Exatamente o que eu estava procurando. Muito Obrigado. E com isso aprendi um pouco mais de AngularJs

Comment: Na verdade eu nem usei nada específico do angular além do que você já tinha, meus complementos foram JS normal mesmo.